# Trying to format my PC but it keeps booting in Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, bios

I've been trying to go back to Windows 10, the factory-OS of my computer, from Ubuntu 18.04. The first thing I tried was changing the boot priority in the BIOS. As expected a device called ubuntu was first and then came Windows Boot Manager. I set Windows Boot Manager first but after exiting the BIOS saving the changes Ubuntu just started as it normally does. After trying every parameter in the Boot settings of the BIOS nothing changes, ubuntu reappears as first in the boot priority. I even tried disabling booting devices but somehow another device called ubuntu appeared as first again. After that I tried to boot from a USB with Windows 10 on it but nothing. 
Another thing I tried was using the Novo button (My computer is Lenovo) which shows the option to do a system recovery but still nothing. Somehow  I also managed to get GRUB to show up and the only booting option was Ubuntu.
Keep in mind that Ubuntu is the only OS installed in this computer. Please help D:

Comment: The EFI boot menu entry only works if Windows is still installed. If not you'll have to boot from USB installation media and install it again, preferably in dual-boot. Recovery also works only uf the recovery partition hasn't been deleted. It seems that you didn't plan correctly when you installed Ubuntu. Booting from USB requires it to have been correctly made. How did you do it? That's thr only thing that matters.

Comment: If you cannot boot Windows 10 from USB, you might have changed some settings in the BIOS when installing Ubuntu. Check especially anything connected to UEFI/Legacy boot and Secure boot. For UEFI boot the disk must be formatted as GPT.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Mmm unfortunately I don't remember what I did exactly. The computer came with Windows 10 then I installed Debian then I went back to Windows 10 but installed Ubuntu in a partition and then somehow Ubuntu became the only one. I think I did delete the recovery partition once.

Comment: @harrymc I used the windows manager to make the USB bootable so I don't know how it was formatted. I'll check into that.

Comment: I was referring to the internal disk.